# How to delete Eclipse from my machine?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to delete the eclipse folder and all the time i get a message : "The action can not be completed , because the folder or a file in it is open in another program.Close and try again."
This is so annoying and I can not figure out how to remove this folder so I can put a fresh copy. 
In task manager there is no program assoiciatied with Eclipse running.
Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: Close your file manager, and other programs

Comment: if you're using the ADT Eclipse, then there is a chance that ADB is running. I'd recommend trying to restart into Safe Mode and deleting it then.

Comment: reboot would help you, then try delete it right after

Comment: After a restart I was able to delete it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, try killing the **javaw.exe** process.